# Is pattern matching tuples not fully lazy?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I ran across some very unintuitive behavior in Haskell and am not sure if it is a bug in Haskell or not. If this is intended behavior, what specifically causes the infinite loop?

```
import Data.Function (fix)

main=putStrLn$show$fst$
    fix (\rec-> (\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) rec)
```

Infinite loops, I assume because to pattern match rec into rec (a1,a2) it evaluates. But I feel like it shouldn't need to because everything will match. For example these all work correctly:

```
    fix (\rec-> (\a->(3,7)) rec)
    fix (\rec-> (\a->let (a1,a2)=a in (3,7)) rec)
```

Interestingly this exits with error

```
    fix (\rec-> (\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) undefined)
```

But I could have sworn the original code where I encountered this behavior (which was more complicated) would actually work in this case. I could try to recreate it.

Comment: Try `fix (\rec-> (\(~(a1,a2))->(3,7)) rec)`. See here: https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-580003.17

Comment: @alias, the parentheses around `~(a1,a2)` are redundant.

Comment: actually I get a parse error without them

Comment: @dfeuer Not unless you're willing to put a space between the lambda and the tilda. As Darren Smith observed, otherwise you get a parse error.

Comment: @alias, well, I am willing to do so. I thought about mentioning the space, but then worried I was getting too verbose. *sigh*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Correct, tuple pattern matches are not lazy. In fact, with two notable exceptions, *no pattern match is lazy*. To a first approximation, the "point" of pattern matching is to force evaluation of the scrutinee of the match.

Of course, a pattern match may appear in a place where laziness means it is never performed; for example,

```
const 3 (case loop of (_, _) -> "hi!")
```

will not loop. But that's not because the match is lazy -- rather, it's because `const` is lazy and never causes the match to be performed. Your `let` example is similar, as the semantics of `let` is that variables bound by it are not forced before evaluating the body of the `let`.

One of the two notable exceptions is a special pattern modifier, `~`; putting `~` before a pattern says to make the match lazy and, consequently, is a claim to the compiler that the modified pattern *always matches*. (If it doesn't match, you get a crash once one of the bound variables is forced, not the usual fall-through-to-next-pattern behavior!) So, one fix for your `fix` is:

```
fix (\rec -> (\ ~(a1, a2) -> (3, 7)) rec)
```

Of course, the explicit name for `rec` isn't needed. You could just as well write:

```
fix (\ ~(a1, a2) -> (3, 7))
```

The other notable exception is newtype matching, which is not relevant here.

Comment: I would like to add that pattern matching in `where` clauses is also lazy and that tuples are not special in this regard.

Comment: "tuple pattern matches are not lazy" the _real_ question is why is this even relevant. i.e. why `(\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) rec` == `case rec of (a1,a2) -> (3,7)` and not `let (a1,a2) = rec in (3,7)` (where tuple pattern matches _in `let`_ are of course fully lazy (as you mention), i.e. let doesn't force the match but case does, so the question is why the lambda application reduces via case and not via let -- i.e. where in the Report does it say so? (not why this choice was made, historically)).

Comment: @WillNess The Report says so [here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3).

Comment: @WillNess it's a bit silly for tuples, but for general pattern matches it makes sense to raise an error as soon as it happens (when the argument passed in does _not_ match the one pattern the lambda can process), rather than deferring it any longer.

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks. maybe it's worth being mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @WillNess, I think the mistake was in making *outermost* pattern matching lazy in `let` and `where`. This leads to a counterintuitive mismatch between outermost and other pattern matches.

Comment: @dfeuer you mean in the language design, with nested patterns? `let ((a,b),c) = undefined in 3` works, what other pattern matches did you have in mind?

Comment: @WillNess, `let ((_, _), c) = (undefined, 3) in c` is not as obvious as it could be.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks for the clarification. so there's no staging in matching, it's either done whole, or isn't done at all. indeed staging would be more intuitive.

Comment: @WillNess, staging has to be explicit with `~`. Except the outermost one doesn't need `~` in `let` or `where` because it's an exception to the rule. Exceptions are bad for comprehensibility.

Comment: @dfeuer right, I think I remember seeing somewhere (in the Report?) stated that `let`'s patterns have an implicit `~` in front of them.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I think it is worth noting that tuple is not considered irrefutable because it is defined with data instead of newtype (even though it could be - and I would argue should be). And so that is why the ~ works that @alias mentioned.

Comment: @DarrenSmith, no, tuples could not be defined with `newtype`. Only single constructor, *single field* types can. And whether they *should* be depends on context (usually yes, sometimes no).

Answer (score 1):

Tuple (or any other) pattern match is lazy if in `let`, not lazy if in `case`. [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67995144/is-pattern-matching-tuples-not-fully-lazy/67995445#comment120193828_67995445), a lambda application is reduced [via `case`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3), not via `let`.

*(correction: for a refutable pattern `pat`, `(\pat -> ...) val` is the same as `(\x -> case x of pat -> ...) val` == `let x = val in case x of pat -> ...`, so it's not that the reduction is done via `case`, but that the identity `(\pat -> ...)` == `(\x -> case x of pat -> ...)` [must hold](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-260003.3)).*

Thus your code reduces as

```
fix (\rec-> (\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) rec)
=
let { x = (\rec-> (\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) rec) x } in x
=
let { x = (\(a1,a2)->(3,7)) x } in x
=
let { x = (\y -> case y of (a1,a2)->(3,7)) x } in x
=
let { x = case x of {(a1,a2)->(3,7)} } in x
```

and that's why the pattern match for `x` against `(_,_)` is performed *before* it is revealed that it <s>is</s> would be `(3,7)` (but isn't!).

So, Haskell is *not* a declarative language. Its semantics is by *least* fixed point.

Comment: Why does "semantics by least fixed point" imply "not a declarative language"?

Comment: A vague thought I had. From bottom and (3,7), Haskell chooses the least one, the bottom. A "declarative" language could in theory choose the tuple. @DanielWagner

Comment: What should `fix id` do in your idea of a declarative language?

Comment: diverge, I guess. or maybe do nothing? yes, certainly, do nothing. but `[y | x <- [1..], y <- []]` would just be `[]`.

Comment: maybe such a language would be like Prolog, where we can have "free", not-yet-instantiated logical variables, which can still take on any value...

Comment: Both purely functional and pure logical languages are normally considered declarative.

Comment: @dfeuer what about my list comprehension example? somehow it bothers me that in Haskell it diverges...

Comment: I don't understand what "do nothing" means. It has to have *some* value, right? Diverge is a fine answer, that comes from choosing the least fixed point. But why wouldn't it choose, say, 42? And if you are okay with it choosing 42, does this mean you demand that all declarative languages be nondeterministic? Does it mean that all declarative languages must avoid type erasure??

Comment: in Prolog I can write `X=X` and have it become more specified later in the code that follows. `X=X` does nothing, in Prolog. `X`'s value is, "no value yet". yes, there's time leakage here... maybe it makes it less declarative? BTW I treat Prolog here as a functional language, leaving its backtracking "abilities" aside. @DanielWagner these logvars are like named C pointers, pointing at NULL at first, say (or some special "NULL" value)

Comment: @DanielWagner re type erasure, I'd imagine most certainly so, yes, keep the types. types are knowledge. type erasure is needed to get the most performant code, yes? so I imagine a run-time system which keeps all the knowledge it has, and compiles pieces of code as needed to run them, into the performant code without types present. but it's just an operational substrate. it's just like JIT compiler. compilation is not a lofty goal, it's just a necessary evil. :)

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what your definition of declarative language is (maybe "==Prolog"?), but it certainly doesn't seem to be quite the same as how other people understand that term. As for your `[y | x <- [1..], y <- []]`, consider using [`cartesianProduct (\x y -> y) [1..] []`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/universe-base-1.1.2/docs/Data-Universe-Helpers.html#v:cartesianProduct).

Comment: How would you propose list comprehensions should work? Their current behavior is quite predictable. Making your expression converge requires some special-case cleverness.

Comment: @DanielWagner ah, that's nice. an additional level of "indirection"/interpretation/ saves the day! (as usual).

Comment: @dfeuer I'm not proposing changing them in Haskell, just point out something that seems problematic. BTW it might indeed be related to the "fairness" of enumeration (as D.W.'s comment just above shows).